# Set Angularjs Service data to Controller Variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-services

I am trying to set the controllers scope variable to the data, however no luck. The console.log in the controller shows undefined. Appreciate the help!

My angular service has the following code --

```
service('VyrtEventService', ['$http', function($http) {
  var events = [];

  this.getArtistEvents = function(artistId) {
    var url = '/api/users/' + artistId + '/';

    var promise = $http.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      events = data.artist.events;
      console.log(events);
      return events;
    }).catch(function(error) {
      status = 'Unable to load artist data: ' + error.message;
      console.log(status);
    });

    return promise;
  };
}]);
```

And I am referencing it in the controller as follows --

```
VyrtEventService.getArtistEvents($scope.artistId).then(function(data){
    $scope.events = data.data.artist.events;
});

console.log($scope.events);
```

Comment: Can you show the controller code?

Comment: controller('VyrtEventCtrl', ['$scope', 'VyrtEventService', function($scope, VyrtEventService) {

 $scope.artist;
 $scope.events;
 $scope.active_event_id;
 $scope.status;

 VyrtEventService.getArtistEvents($scope.artistId).then(function(data){
  $scope.events = data.data.artist.events;
 });

 console.log($scope.events);
}]);

Comment: First try with assigning `$scope.events=[];` in declaration `$scope.events = data.data.artist.events;` make sure you are getting List in   `data.data.artist.events; `

Comment: no luck, data.data is consoling right, but the $scope.events isn't being set to this

Comment: Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: When you're doing `console.log($scope.events)` it would be undefined cause your `VyrtEventService.getArtistEvents` promise hasn't resolved yet. Put your console.log inside the call back where you set `$scope.events`

Comment: thanks user2341, that works for me. however, is there a way to set it to the scope, and use it outside the .then function? i intend to use it in various places in the controller if possible

Comment: Turns out that while the console.log of the scope variable is showing undefined, it actually does set as I am pulling the scope variables in the directive and its showing the values just fine.

Comment: its my lack of understanding, but perhaps the console.log happens before the variable is actually set?

Answer (score 0):

You should just set `$scope.events = data` in your controller cause your promise already returns `data.artist.events` when it resolves

Comment: no luck. data.data.artist.events gives me something, but assigning it to $scope.events, doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

To pass scope to service from anywhere in controller. Make sure you inject service .

```
controllersModule.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $filter, $http, $compile, ngTableParams, **FactoryYouwant**) 
    {

        **FactoryYouwant**.getdata($scope.**scopeYoutwantTopass**).then (function(responseData){    
        var ResponseFromServer =responseData.data;
    }

in service

    controllersModule.factory('**FactoryYouwant**, function($http) {
        var responseData = null;

        return {
            getdata : function(**data**){     (you dont have to use $)                  
                responseData = $http.post or whatever actually gets you data;
                return responseData;
            }

          };
    });
```

I hope this helps you to call get data from service anywhere in controller.